# Confused about leal. Does it access the contents of a memory address, too?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, att

32bit, AT&T/GAS syntax

I get a little confused between what is being stored into a register sometimes. Is it a value or is it an address?

Let's say the start of our function has this in its code.

```
 movl 12(%ebp), %eax //Get i
 leal (%eax,%eax,2), %eax //Compute 3*i
```

So 12(%ebp) isn't the value of i itself. It has the address of where the value of i is actually located in memory. So that means &i is being sent to the register eax.

The next line 
Leal. Does it actually dereference the address that's in eax?

Here's what I think leal does. It's about loading an address and sending it to %eax register.

If I follow my definition, does it actual take the &i in eax and multiply it by 2, then add itself again? So it's &i + &i*2? Obviously that can't be right. If &i was FFFF FFF1 (impossible, but just an example), it's going to calculate an address that's outside of my memory range.

Shouldn't the line be ...

```
  movl (%eax,%eax,2), %eax
```

where it will access the memory location stored in eax and see that at that mem address, i could equal, say 5, for example.

```
 (If you wanted to know the rest of the code, here it is. It's about get an array element's address)
 movl 16(%ebp), %edx //Get j
 sall $2, %edx Compute //j*4
 addl 8(%ebp), %edx //ComputexA+4j
 movl (%edx,%eax,4), %eax //Read fromM[xA+4j+12i]
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although `lea` stands for "load effective address", it does not actually perform a load. Instead it calculates the address that the memory operand would reference, and leaves that value in the destination register. Perhaps it should have been called "calculate effective address".

In this case it is simply being (ab)used to calculate reg + reg * 2, a multiply by 3. It looks like the x3 has been factored out of a multiply by 12 (the array element size, I suppose) in order to use addressing modes to perform the multiplication work more efficiently. This is a pretty common pattern in x86 code.

Answer (score 0):

Meaning of arguments of mnemonics varies greatly in general.
You should think arguments of "movl" and arguments of leal differently.

```
movl 12(%ebp), %eax //Get i
```

movl means "move long data from the location of first argument to the location of second argument."
12(%ebp) is a location on memory which 12 above from 'base pointer' (%ebp). That is location of variable "i" on the memory also. That assignment is determined by compiler and compiler output that information in comment.

"#eax" is a location of register on chip named "ax".

To convine these together , "movl 12(%ebp)" means move data at  &i to register "ax".

```
leal (%eax,%eax,2), %eax //Compute 3*i
```

leal means "do mathematical operation of first argument and store result to the location of second argument".

(%eax,%eax,2) means ('ax' * 2) + 'ax'.  ('ax' means value stored in register "ax")

As the result, value of 'ax' is multiplied by 3.
"ax" had a value of i, so 'ax' becomes a value i*3 after leal is executed.